# AWS: Execute a task after 1 year has elapsed

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs

Basically, I have a web service that receives a small json payload (an event) a few times per minute, say 60. This event must be sent to an SQS queue only after 1 year has elapsed (it's ok to have it happen a few hours sooner or later, but the day of month should be exactly the same).

This means I'll have to store more than 31 million events somewhere before the first one should be sent to the SQS queue.

I thought about using SQS message timers, but they have a limit of only 15 minutes, and as pointed out by @Charlie Fish, it's weird to have an element lurking around on a queue for such a long time.

A better possibility could be to schedule a lambda function using a Cron expression for each event (I could end up with millions or billions of scheduled lambda functions in a year, if I don't hit an AWS limit well before that).

Or I could store these events on DynamoDB or RDS.

What would be the recommended / most cost-effective way to handle this using AWS services? Scheduled lambda functions? DynamoDB? PostgreSQL on RDS? Or something entirely different?

And what if I have 31 billion events per year instead of 31 million?

I cannot afford to loose ANY of those events.

Comment: Just edited giving a bit more detail about some things to consider with DynamoDB

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DynamoDB is a reasonable option, as is RDS - SQS for long term storage is not a good choice. However - if you want to keep your costs down, I may suggest another: accumulate the events for a single 24 hour period (or a smaller interval if that is desirable), and write that set of data out as an S3 object instead of keeping it in DynamoDB. You could employ dynamodb or rds (or just about anything else) as a place to accumulate events for the day (or hour) before it then writes out that data to S3 as a single set of data for the interval.

Each S3 object could be named appropriately, either indicating the date/time it was created, or the data/time it needs to be used, i.e. 20190317-1400 to indicate that on March 17th, 2019 at 2PM this file needs to be used.

I would imagine a lambda function, called by a cloudwatch event that is triggered every 60 minutes, scans your s3 bucket looking for files that are due to be used, and it then reads in the json data and puts them into an SQS queue for further processing and moves the processed s3 object to another 'already processed' bucket

Your storage costs would be minimal (especially if you batch them up by day or hour), S3 has 11 9's of durability, and you can archive older events off to Glacier if you want to keep them around even after the are processed.

DynamoDB is a great product, it provides redundant storage, and super high performance - but I see nothing in your requirements to that would warrant incurring that cost or requiring the performance of DynamoDB; and why keep millions of records of data in a 'always on' database when you know in advance that you don't need to use or see the records until a year from now.

Comment: Keep in mind if you are getting a ton of requests per second or per millisecond that naming system won’t work. You need to ensure files don’t overwrite one another in S3 if you use that naming system. S3 would be a good option but as you mentioned DynamoDB might have better performance. All depends on what exactly the OP is trying to do and what sacrifices the OP is willing to make.

Comment: Thats why I suggested batching up items by the day or hour - the OP was not concerned about messages being processed at the right minute/second - just as long as they were processed that day - accumulate the current events for the hour (or day) in something like dynamodb, write them out as a single object at the end of the day/hour.

Comment: I misunderstood. But it's a good point to reiterate to ensure there are no collisions. Easy mistake to make if you aren't thinking far enough ahead.

Comment: I really liked the idea of using S3 here. No need to pay for DynamoDB for my use case. I'll schedule a daily lambda to get all events from the previous day (~86k) and store it in a compressed file in S3. Another daily lambda will read the file that is due for the day from S3 and queue up its events on SQS.

Answer (score 2):

I mean you could store some form of data in DynamoDB, and run some daily Lambda task to query for all the items that are greater than a year old, remove those from DynamoDB and import it into SQS.

As you mentioned SQS doesn't have this functionality built in. So you need to store the data using some other technology. DynamoDB seems like a responsible choice based on what you have mentioned above.

Of course you also have to think about if doing a cron task once per day is sufficient for your task. Do you need it to be **exactly** after 1 year? Is it acceptable to have it be one year and a few days? Or one year and a few weeks? What is the window that is acceptable for importing into SQS?

Finally, the other question you have to think about is if SQS is even reasonable for your application. Having a queue that has a 1 year delay seems kinda strange. I could be wrong, but you might want to consider something besides SQS because SQS is meant for much more instantaneous tasks. See the examples on [this page](https://aws.amazon.com/sqs/pricing/) (`Decouple live user requests from intensive background work: let users upload media while resizing or encoding it`, `Allocate tasks to multiple worker nodes: process a high number of credit card validation requests`, etc.). None of those examples are really meant for a year of wait time before executing. At the end of the day it depends on your use case, but off the top of my head I can't think of a situation that makes sense for delaying entry into an SQS queue for a year. There seem to be much better ways to handle this, but again I don't know your specific use case.

**EDIT** another question is if your data is consistent? Is the amount of data you need to store consistent? How about the format? What about the number of events per second? You mention that you don’t want to lose any data. For sure build in error handling and backup systems. But for DynamoDB it doesn’t scale the best if one moment you store 5 items then the next moment you want to store 5 million items. If you set your capacity to account for 5 million then it is fine. But the question is will the amount of data and frequency be consistent or not?